# Combined Index performance with optional where clause

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table with the following columns:

```
id-> PK

customer_id-> index

store_id-> index

order_date-> index

last_modified-> index

other_columns...

other_columns...
```

I have three single column index. I also have a customer_id_store_id index which is a foreign key constraint referencing other tables.

id, customer_id, store_id are char(36) which is UUID. order_date is datetime and last_modifed is UNIX timestamp.

I want to gain some performance by removing all index and adding one with (customer_id, store_id, order_date). Most queries will have these fields in the where clause. But sometimes the store_id will not be needed.

What is the best approach? to add "store_id IS NOT NULL" in the where clause or creating the index this way (customer_id, order_date, store_id).

I also frequently need to query the table by last_modified field (where clause includes customer_id=, store_id=, last_modified>).

As I only have a single column index on it and there are hundreds of customers who is insert/updating the tables, more often the index scans rows more than necessary. Is it better to create another index (customer_id, store_id, last_modified) or leave it as it is? Or add this column to the previous index making it four columns composite index. But then again the order_date is irrelevant here and omitting it might result the index not being used as intended.

The query works fast on customers that don't have many rows possibly using the customer_id index there. But for customers with large amount of data, this isn't optimal. More often I need only few days of data.

Can anyone please advise what's the best index in this scenario.

Comment: It's practically impossible to help you unless you show the queries you're hoping to optimize.  That being said, lots of single-column indexes are generally considered harmful.

Comment: Please consider making an [edit] to your question to give more information. Also, read this. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056

Answer (score 2):

It is true that lots of single column indexes on a MySQL table are generally considered harmful.

A query with

```
WHERE customer_id=constant AND store_id=constant AND last_modified>=constant
```

will be accelerated by an index on `(customer_id, store_id, last_modified)`. Why? The MySQL query planner can random-access the index to the first item it needs to retrieve, then scan the index sequentially.  That same index works for

```
WHERE customer_id=constant AND store_id=constant 
  AND last_modified>=constant
  AND last_modified< constant + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

BUT, that index will not be useful for a query with just

```
WHERE store_id=constant AND last_modified>constant
```

or

```
WHERE customer_id=constant AND store_id IS NOT NULL AND last_modified>=constant
```

For the first of those query patterns you need `(store_id, last_modified)` to achieve the ability to sequentially scan the index.

The second of those query patterns requires two different range searches. One is `something IS NOT NULL`. That's a range search because it has to romp through all the non-null values in the column. The second range search is `last_modified>=constant`. That's a range search, because it starts with the first value of `last_modified` that meets the given criterion, and scans to the end of the index.

MySQL indexes are B-trees. That means, essentially, that they're sorted into a particular single order. So, an index is best for accelerating queries that require just one range search. So, the second query pattern is inherently hard to satisfy with an index.

A table can have multiple compound indexes designed to satisfy multiple different query patterns. That's usually the strategy to large tables work well in practical applications.  Each index imposes a little bit of performance penalty on updates and inserts. Indexes also take storage space. But storage is very cheap these days.

If you want to use a compound index to search on multiple criteria, these things must be true:

1. all but one of the criteria must be equality criteria like `store_id = constant`.
2. one criterion can be a range-scan criterion like `last_modified >= constant` or `something IS NOT NULL`.
3. the columns in the index must be ordered so that the columns involved in equality criteria *all* appear, then the the column involved in the range-scan criterion.
4. you may mention other columns after the range scan criterion. But they make up part of a covering index strategy (beyond the scope of this post).

http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a good basic intro to the black art of indexing.

Comment: If I don't need the middle part in some occasion or I want all stores data, will the index (customer_id, store_id, last_modified) work if I change the query as:  WHERE customer_id=constant AND store_id IS NOT NULL AND last_modified>constant.

Comment: No, no, a thousand times no. `IS NOT NULL` is a notorious antipattern when you're trying for fast queries. See my edit.

Comment: Great! So, I will create (customer_id, order_date, store_id). All queries will have the customer_id, order_date and occasionally store_id. That means this will work fine in all of those queries. I will probably create (customer_id, store_id, last_modified) as the query will search in that order. Apart from more disk space, is there any downsides to this? Also is it better to create the combined index first before dropping the single column index as some won't be necessary? If i delete them first, the query optimizer will use other index which can be costly.

Comment: No, your  indexing strategy is incorrect, with respect. `order_date` should be last in the index. Read my latest edit. And go read use-the-index-luke.

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciated. I added some index(customer_id, order_date) and (store_id, order_date) and the query planner seems to be using the right index and the time is faster as well. It shows how little I knew about index.

Comment: Right. SQL is easy. Indexing is complex. Especially with a low-end SQL server system like MySQL.  Other brands sometimes say "hey you! you need this index! Want me to create it for you?"